# When transplanting asparagus seedlings should part of the stem be buried?

Tags: transplanting, seedlings

I know it is a good idea to bury part of the stem of tomatoes when transplanting as they will sprout new roots along the stem.  I am wondering if something similar applies to asparagus.

My asparagus seedling (started from seed) is rather thin in the stem and I am hoping to bury part of it so it will have less plant to support.

Answer (score 2):

It should be fine, I doubt they will root like tomatoes... Monocots grow adventitious roots, I wouldnt worry too much about it, unless you live in an area with a lot of water... Then avoid it.

Comment: I have since read that people plant asparagus very deep so that they can till over them without hurting the roots... (as they are perennials)... I haven't done this yet myself so some research could be in order